# Reputation rewards are listed in reverse in Help Center > Badges

Tags: support, reputation, badges

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges and look at the tiered badges (e.g. Curious, Inquisitive, Socratic), their associated reputation rewards seem to be backward. So for the three badges listed above:

Curious (Bronze) 261.8k awarded

Inquisitive (Silver) 26.1k awarded

Socratic (Gold) 3k awarded

I can't think of any reason why this would make sense, so I feel reasonably confident they are listed in reverse order for some reason. The pattern holds for most, but not quite all, of the tiered badges.

Comment: _their associated reputation rewards_? not sure what you mean? You don't get rep along with a badge. The number signifies how many people received it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badges within each individual category are listed in ascending order of achievement. The least impressive badge (the bronze) is listed first, then the middle (the silver), and finally the most impressive version (the gold).

The numerical counts off to the side are the total number of times that badge has been awarded<sup>*</sup>. They don't have anything to do with reputation.

Reputation and badges are only distantly connected; as it says at the top of the page:

> Besides gaining reputation with your questions and answers, you receive badges for being especially helpful. Badges appear on your profile page, flair, and your posts.

__
<sub>* Sometimes, this is equivalent to the total number of users who have been awarded that badge—but not always. Some badges can be awarded more than once to the same user. The "awarded" counts shown on the page are actually the total number of times that badge has been awarded on the site.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm...not sure how you're arriving at this conclusion.

It's expected to see more bronze badges, since they're the easiest of the tiered badges to earn.  I'd expect silver badges to be harder to earn (although a 90% drop is a bit of a surprise, it's not unexpected).  Gold should be the **hardest** to earn so you'd see even *fewer* users with that badge.

I see no bug here.  I see appropriate-feeling tiers.  The issue with this specific badge is that we can't really audit it well, since this is one of those badges that relies on information normal users can't see, but I'm fairly confident that this feels correct.

Comment: I think OP misunderstood the numbers to mean rep awarded with the badge..

Comment: @suraj:  That'd *almost* make sense...but there's nothing explicit in that display that even mentions reputation.

Comment: In fact, reputation is explicitly mentioned at the top: *"Besides gaining reputation with your questions and answers, you receive badges…"* So, this is pretty clearly *not* about reputation.

Comment: @suraj Yeah, that's exactly what I did. I'm new to Stack Overflow and I had just spent too many hours staring at a particular problem, so when I stumbled onto the badges page I wasn't thinking strait